# MySQLi insert problems - PHP 7.2.10

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i've been working in a self project that aims to be a Nintendo 3DS database.
However, at the insert part it gives the following error.

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

I've check at all the files that are being requested and all of them doesn't have that '' thing.

Below are the codes:

**addgame.php**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
$c = connectDB();
define('IMAGE_WIDTH',200);
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT',200);
$boxDir = "../boxdb/";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$desc = $_POST['description'];
$rel = $_POST['releaseDate'];
$reg = $_POST['region'];
$gen = $_POST['genre'];
$box = $_FILES['box']['name'];
$temp_box = $_FILES['box']['tmp_name'];
$qrName = '../qrdb/' . $name . '.png';
$qr = QRcode::png($link, $qrName);
move_uploaded_file($temp_box, $boxDir.$box);
if(!empty($reg) and is_array($reg)) {
    $regArr = implode(' , ',$reg);
}
if(!empty($gen) and is_array($gen)) {
    $genArr = implode(' , ',$gen);
}
$ins = mysqli_query($c,"INSERT INTO db(gameName,ciaLink,gameDesc, releaseDate, region, genre, gameBox,qr) VALUES('$name','$link','$desc','$rel','$regArr','$genArr','$temp_box','$qr'");
if($ins){
    echo 'OK';
}
else{
    echo mysqli_error($c);
}
?>
```

**homereg.php**

```
<form action="../libs/addGame.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gameName">Name of the Game</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="gameName" placeholder="Ex.: Super Mario 3D Land...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gameName">Direct Download Game Link (for Google Drive, use <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/" target="_blank">this</a>)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link" id="gameName" placeholder="Ex.: https://example.com/gamename.cia">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gameDesc">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="gameDesc" placeholder="Game Description" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gameDate">Release Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="releaseDate" id="gameDate" placeholder="Release Date">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Regions where game was released</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="gameGen" name="region[]">
      <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
      <option value="JPN">JPN</option>
      <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gameGen">Genre - You can select more than one if applies</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="gameGen" name="genre[]">
      <option value="Action">Action</option>
      <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
      <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
      <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gameBox">Game box image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="box" id="gameBox">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="Add">
</form>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASS","");
define("DB","3ds");
function connectDB(){
    $c = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
    return $c;
}
?>
```

What can be possibly wrong?
And if it helps, i'm on Windows 7 using WampServer64 3.1.4.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Echo out the Statement and share it

Comment: Don't insert parameters like this, any of your parameters may contain content that will break the query, as pointed out by Jens, look into prepared statements, then the management of the parameters is handled for you.

Comment: Link and Name has the same id in your html

Comment: @Jens True, yet that shouldn't break their code; only with JS would it.

Comment: Regarding the edit. Either post your own answer or delete the question. The solution should not be in the question.

Comment: Done, @FunkFortyNiner.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what was my mistake, at the $ins query i was closing the insert inside the values and not closing the query. Ps.: Here is the corrected code with prepared statements as mentioned by @Jens:

**addGame.php**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
$c = connectDB();
define('IMAGE_WIDTH',200);
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT',200);
$boxDir = "../boxdb/";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$desc = $_POST['description'];
$rel = $_POST['releaseDate'];
$reg = $_POST['region'];
$gen = $_POST['genre'];
$box = $_FILES['box']['name'];
$temp_box = $_FILES['box']['tmp_name'];
$qrFolder = '../qrdb/' . $name . '.png';
$qr = QRcode::png($link, $qrFolder);
$qrName = $name . '.png';
move_uploaded_file($temp_box, $boxDir.$box);
if(!empty($reg) and is_array($reg)) {
    $regArr = implode(' , ',$reg);
}
if(!empty($gen) and is_array($gen)) {
    $genArr = implode(' , ',$gen);
}
$stmt = $c->prepare("INSERT INTO db(gameName,ciaLink,gameDesc, releaseDate, region, genre, gameBox,qr) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$name,$link,$desc,$rel,$regArr,$genArr,$box,$qrName);
$stmt->execute();
echo "New game added successfully";
$stmt->close();
$c->close();
?>
```

Thanks guys!